# CakePHP 2.8 saveAll Creates Two Records Instead of One

Tags: cakephp-2.0, saving-data

I'm cloning a milestone record with associated data. I first find the data from the source milestone, then change the contents of the array and remove all 'id' fields. Then I attempt a 'saveAll'. All the associated data is being created properly but the 'milestones' table now has 2 new records instead of 1. The second record contains the ID used by the associated data, so why does the first record even exist?

**The Data (simplified) and Call:**

```
    $test = array(
        'Milestone' => array(
            'name' => 'Clone Test',
            'customer_status' => '',
            'time_to_complete' => '1',
            'is_active' => true,
        ),
        'MilestoneAlert' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'Clone Test',
                'type' => 'customer',
                'milestone_alert_type_id' => '0',
                'email' => null,
                'subject' => 'First alert!',
                'message' => 'Add a message',
                'recipient_name' => '',
                'is_active' => true,
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'name' => 'Clone Test 1',
                'type' => 'customer',
                'milestone_alert_type_id' => '0',
                'email' => null,
                'subject' => 'Second alert!',
                'message' => 'Add a message',
                'recipient_name' => '',
                'is_active' => true,
            )
        ),
        'MilestoneCondition' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'Clone Test',
                'condition' => 'First condition.',
                'is_active' => true,
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'name' => 'Clone Test 1',
                'condition' => 'Second condition.',
                'is_active' => true,
            )
        )
    );
    $this->loadModel('Milestone');
    $this->Milestone->create();
    $this->Milestone->saveAll($test);
```

**In Model/Milestone.php:**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'MilestoneAlert' => array(
        'className' => 'MilestoneAlert',
        'foreignKey' => 'milestone_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'MilestoneCondition' => array(
        'className' => 'MilestoneCondition',
        'foreignKey' => 'milestone_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => 'MilestoneCondition.order',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

**In Model/MilestoneAlert.php:**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Milestone' => array(
        'className' => 'Milestone',
        'foreignKey' => 'milestone_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

**In Model/MilestoneCondition.php:**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Milestone' => array(
        'className' => 'Milestone',
        'foreignKey' => 'milestone_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

After running the method, there are two records in 'milestone_conditions', two records in 'milestone_alerts', and *two identical* records in 'milestones'. How do I keep it from creating two 'milestone' records?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the original data like this:

```
$test= $this->Milestone->findById('insert your id');
$this->Milestone->create(); // Create a new record
$this->Milestone->saveAll($test,array('deep' => true)); // And save it
```